# Date Display: How to hide part of repeat rule?

Tags: 7, datetime

When displaying recurring event dates for end users I would like to hide a part of the repeat rule (the until date has no meaning for end users):

Current display:

> Repeats every week every Thursday until Mon Dec 31 2012

Expected display:

> Repeats every week every Thursday

How to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

The recurrence description is defined in [date_repeat_rrule_description()](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/blob/283ad110c529b084603a3f17eeac49c516562f53:/date_repeat/date_repeat.module#l258) in date_repeat.module.

At this time, there is no way for themes to change it. See this issue: http://drupal.org/node/342665

**EDIT**

Actually, you may override `theme_date_repeat_field()`, which calls `date_repeat_rrule_description()`. You could call your own version of that function to customize the display.

This would leave the contrib modules untouched, but you would be duplicating some effort and have more code to maintain.