# How to change date repeat display format

Tags: 7, datetime

I am using date module & date repeat API but now i want to change repeat date format.Now repeat date is display in "Repeats 5 days " but i want to show only "5 days " instead of "Repeats 5 days"

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30548/date-display-how-to-hide-part-of-repeat-rule) was raised before. There is still no way to override the format of the Repeat rule via theme functions. The answer that was given for the linked question provides a possible workaround (quoted below).

> you may override `theme_date_repeat_field()`, which calls
>   `date_repeat_rrule_description()`. You could call your own version of
>   that function to customize the display.
>
> This would leave the contrib modules untouched, but you would be
>   duplicating some effort and have more code to maintain.

There is an active issue for Date Repeat sub-module - [Make Repeat Date Format/Display More Flexible](https://www.drupal.org/node/1387276) which did not receive enough attention.

You can also patch the `date_repeat.module` directly and keep track of it during updates, but that is obviously not a desired way to go about this.

The function that constructs the output of the string you need to change is

```
function date_repeat_rrule_description()
```

check `$output` variable - that is what you are trying to modify.